# How can I access a specific field in a named subquery when the field name might not be unique?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a routine that can accept an SQL query as a string and the [table].[primaryKey] of the primary record in the returned dataset, then wrap that original query to implement pagination (return records 40-49 when requesting page 4 and 10 records per page).

The dataset returned by the original queries will frequently contain multiple instances of the primary record, one for each occurrence of supporting records.  For the example provided, if a customer has three phone numbers on record the results for that customer in the original query would look like:

```
{5;  John Smith;  205 W. Fort St;  17;  Home;  123-123-4587}
{5;  John Smith;  205 W. Fort St;  18;  Work;  123-123-8547}
{5;  John Smith;  205 W. Fort St;  19;  Mobile;  123-123-1147}
```

I'm almost there, I think, with the following query:

```
DECLARE @PageNumber int = 4;
DECLARE @RecordsPerPage int = 10;

WITH OriginalQuery AS (
    SELECT [Customer].[Id],
           [Customer].[Name],
           [Customer].[Address],
           [Phone].[Id],
           [Phone].[Type],
           [Phone].[Number]
    FROM [Customer] INNER JOIN [Phone] ON [Customer].[Id] = [Phone].[CustomerId]
)

SELECT [WrappedQuery].[RowNumber], [OriginalQuery].* FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) [RowNumber], *
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT [OriginalQuery].[{Customer.Id}] [PrimaryKey]
        FROM [OriginalQuery]
        ) [RuwNumberQuery]
    ) [WrappedQuery]
INNER JOIN [OriginalQuery] ON [WrappedQuery].[PrimaryKey] = [OriginalQuery].[{Customer.Id}]
WHERE [WrappedQuery].[RowNumber] >= @PageNumber
  AND [WrappedQuery].[RowNumber] < @PageNumber + @RecordsPerPage
```

This solution performs a SELECT DISTINCT on the primary key for the Primary (Customer) record and uses the SQL routine Row_Number() then joins the result with the results of the original query such that each unique primary (customer) record is numbered 1 - {end of file}, and I can pull only the RowNumber counts that I want.

But because OriginalQuery may have multiple fields named Id (from different tables), I can't figure out how to properly access [Customer].[Id] in my SELECT DISTINCT clause of [RowNumberQuery]  or in the INNER JOIN.

Is there a better way to implement pagination at the SQL level, or a more direct method of accessing the field I need from within the subquery based on the table to which it belongs?

**EDIT:**
I've caused confusion in the pagination I am looking for.  I am using Dapper in C# to compile the resulting dataset into individual complex objects, so the goal in the example would be to retrieve customers 31-40 in the list regardless of how many individual records exist for each customer.  If Customer 31 had five phone records, Customer 32 had three phone records, Customer 33 had 1 phone record, and the remaining seven customers had two phone records each, I would expect the resulting dataset to contain 23 records total, but only 10 distinct customers.

**SOLUTION**
Thank you for all of the assistance, and I apologize for those areas I should have clarified sooner.  I am creating a toolset that will allow C# Data Access Libraries to implement a set of standard parameters.  If I have an option to implement the pagination in an internal function that can accept the SQL statement, I can defer to the toolset and not have to remember (or count on others to remember) to add the appropriate text each time.  I'll set it up to return the finished objects, but if I were going to just modify the original query string it would look like:

```
public static string AddPagination(string sql, string primaryKey, Parameter requestParameters)
{
                return $"WITH OriginalQuery AS ({sql.Replace("SELECT ", $"SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY {primaryKey}) AS PrimaryRecordCount, ",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)}) " +
                    $"SELECT TOP ({requestParameters.MaxRecords}) * " +
                    $"FROM OriginalQuery " +
                    $"WHERE PrimaryRecordCount >= 1 + (({requestParameters.PageNumber - 1}) * {requestParameters.RecordsPerPage})" +
                    $"  AND PrimaryRecordCount <= {requestParameters.Page} * {requestParameters.Limit}";
}
```

Comment: Your paging is quite strange, it is not ensuring the same number of rows per page, rather the same number of customers per page. Is that the intention? e.g. Page 1 might contain 10 records for 10 customers all with one phone number, but page 2 might contain 20 records, again 10 customers but each of them have two phone numbers.

Comment: Can you clarify what result you are expecting?  Looking at your current example, it doesn't appear to be pagination as I know it. For example, if you had 15 customers with 3 phone numbers each, and you used PageNumber = 1, RecordsPerPage = 10, you would have 30 results returned. Which means that the calling application can't know how many results are going to be returned based on the input as the number of results is a function of the join, not the pagination parameters.

Comment: This is definitely an argument for not using generic names like `Id` for columns. Is it a `CustomerID`? Cool, call it `CustomerID` everywhere in the schema, then there is never any chance for confusion or collision.

Comment: You can significantly simplify this by using [offset fetch](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-offset-fetch/)

Comment: @GarethD,  I apologize for the confusion on the expected pagination results.  I am using Dapper in C# to compile the resulting dataset into individual complex objects, so the goal in the example would be to retrieve customers 31-40 in the list regardless of how many individual records exist for each customer.  If Customer 31 had five phone records, Customer 32 had three phone records, Customer 33 had 1 phone record, and the remaining customers had two phone records, I would expect the resulting dataset to contain 23 records total, but only 10 distinct customers.

Comment: @David Jacobsen,  I apologize for the confusion on the expected pagination results.  I am using Dapper in C# to compile the resulting dataset into individual complex objects, so the goal in the example would be to retrieve customers 31-40 in the list regardless of how many individual records exist for each customer.  If Customer 31 had five phone records, Customer 32 had three phone records, Customer 33 had 1 phone record, and the remaining customers had two phone records, I would expect the resulting dataset to contain 23 records total, but only 10 distinct customers.

Comment: @tamjap I did think that might be the case, in which case the paging makes sense

Comment: @tamjap I haven't used Dapper before, only EntityFramework, but you may have some issues with my proposed solution of OFFSET and FETCH NEXT as they are provider dependent. Ie, MS SQL SERVER uses OFFSET and FETCH NEXT, MySQL uses LIMIT and OFFSET. So you may need to refactor code if you adjust your provider. 

Though I still suggest not trying to generalize this pagination function. It's going to get confusing when other callers only want 10 rows, or there are 3 joins and you want all records of the first 10 results of the first table join etc.

Comment: @DavidJacobsen You are correct that Offset and Fetch Next would be the better solution were I not dealing with complex objects.  I moved away from EntityFramework because I didn't like having to republish my code whenever someone changed or deleted fields that I wasn't using.  I appreciate your insight very much.

Comment: @tamjap to clarify on EF, you don't need to republish your code when a field you aren't using is changed or deleted as long as you don't define the unused fields in your entity class. If you define your entities to only include fields you are using, then the process that maps the returned data set into objects ignores the returned fields that you didn't define in your entity.

Comment: @DavidJacobsen Huh.  I was using the DB First approach - allowing VisualStudio build the entities, and it always put every field in there, then wouldn't compile when I removed ones I didn't need.  Maybe I just missed someplace I needed to remove the reference.

Comment: @tamjap `OFFSET/FETCH` is a perfectly valid approach even with complex objects, the results from David's second query would return exactly as you are expecting, and in a more efficient manner than in my query using `DENSE_RANK()`. The efficiency difference is negligible in my tests, but SQL Server is optimised for `OFFSET/FETCH` so it is the better solution. My initial assumption was that the need to do the query twice would negate this optimisation, but the benchmarking I did said otherwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give your columns a different alias in your original query, e.g. `[Customer].[Id] AS CustomerId, [Phone].[Id] AS PhoneId...`, then you can reference `OriginalQuery.CustomerId`, or `OriginalQuery.PhoneId`

e.g.

```
DECLARE @PageNumber int = 4;
DECLARE @RecordsPerPage int = 10;

WITH OriginalQuery AS (
    SELECT [Customer].[Id] AS CustomerId,
           [Customer].[Name],
           [Customer].[Address],
           [Phone].[Id] AS PhoneId,
           [Phone].[Type],
           [Phone].[Number]
    FROM [Customer] INNER JOIN [Phone] ON [Customer].[Id] = [Phone].[CustomerId]
)

SELECT [WrappedQuery].[RowNumber], [OriginalQuery].* FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) [RowNumber], *
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT [OriginalQuery].[{Customer.Id}] [PrimaryKey]
        FROM [OriginalQuery]
        ) [RuwNumberQuery]
    ) [WrappedQuery]
INNER JOIN [OriginalQuery] ON [WrappedQuery].[PrimaryKey] = [OriginalQuery].[CustomerId]
WHERE [WrappedQuery].[RowNumber] >= @PageNumber
  AND [WrappedQuery].[RowNumber] < @PageNumber + @RecordsPerPage
```

It's worth noting that your paging logic is wrong too. Currently you are adding page number to the number of pages so you are searching for:

- Page 1: Customers 1 - 10
- Page 2: Customers 2 - 11
- Page 3: Customers 3 - 12

Your logic should be:

```
WHERE [WrappedQuery].[RowNumber] >= 1 + ((@PageNumber - 1) * @RecordsPerPage)
  AND [WrappedQuery].[RowNumber] <= (@PageNumber * @RecordsPerPage)
```

- Page 1: Customers 1 - 10
- Page 2: Customers 11 - 20
- Page 3: Customers 21 - 30

With that being said, you could just use `DENSE_RANK()` Rather than `ROW_NUMBER` which would simplify everything. I think this would give you the same result:

```
DECLARE @PageNumber int = 4;
DECLARE @RecordsPerPage int = 10;

WITH OriginalQuery AS (
    SELECT c.Id AS CustomerId,
           c.Name,
           c.Address,
           p.Id AS PhoneId,
           p.Type,
           p.Number,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY c.Id) AS RowNumber
    FROM Customer AS c INNER JOIN Phone AS p ON c.Id = p.CustomerId
)

SELECT oq.CustomerId, oq.Name, oq.Address, oq.PhoneId, oq.Type, oq.Number
FROM  OriginalQuery AS oq
WHERE oq.RowNumber >= 1 +((@PageNumber - 1) * @RecordsPerPage)
  AND oq.RowNumber <= (@PageNumber * @RecordsPerPage);
```

I've added table aliases to try and make the code a bit cleaner, and also removed all the unnecessary square brackets. This is not necessary, but I personally find them quite hard on the eye, and only use them to escape key words.

Another difference is that in adding `ORDER BY c.CustomerId` you ensure consistent results for your paging. Using `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` implies that you don't care about the order, but you should if you using it for paging.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I think that DENSE_RANK() function is the hidden jewel I needed to make it all work.  I can use a string.replace to change "SELECT" to: $"SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY {table.field}) AS PrimaryRecordNumber,", then adjust the pagination as you suggested.  That silly mistake was just me hurrying to toss it on at the end to show where I was going with it all.

Minor point, in the last line of the pagination piece it should be "op.RowNumber <= (@PageNumber * @RecordsPerPage), not "=".

Answer (score 2):

There are many concerns with what you are trying to do and you might be better off explaining why you are trying to make this process.

> SQL query as a string

You are receiving a SQL query as a string, how are you parsing that string into the OriginalQuery CTE? This has both concerns about sql injection and concerns about global temp tables if you are using those.

Secondly, your example isn't doing pagination as it is commonly understood. If someone were to request page 1, 10 records per page, the calling application would expect to receive the first 10 records of the result set but your example will returns all records for the first 10 customers. Meaning the result could be 40+ if they each had 4 phone numbers as in your example data.

You should take a look at OFFSET and FETCH NEXT, as well as why this requirement to parse an arbitrary SQL string. There is probably a better way to do that.

Here is a rough example using OFFSET and FETCH NEXT from a static query, and returning only @RecordsPerPage number of records.

```
DECLARE @PageNumber int = 1;
DECLARE @RecordsPerPage int = 10;

SELECT [Customer].[Id],
       [Customer].[Name],
       [Customer].[Address],
       [Phone].[Id],
       [Phone].[Type],
       [Phone].[Number]
FROM [Customer] INNER JOIN [Phone] ON [Customer].[Id] = [Phone].[CustomerId]
ORDER BY [Customer].[Id]
OFFSET (@PageNumber-1)*@RecordsPerPage rows
FETCH NEXT @RecordsPerPage ROWS ONLY
```

If you wanted to return all records for the the RecordsPerPage number of entries which have a corresponding phone number, then it would be something like...

```
DECLARE @PageNumber int = 1;
DECLARE @RecordsPerPage int = 10;

SELECT [Customer].[Id],
       [Customer].[Name],
       [Customer].[Address],
       [Phone].[Id],
       [Phone].[Type],
       [Phone].[Number]
FROM [Customer] INNER JOIN [Phone] ON [Customer].[Id] = [Phone].[CustomerId]
WHERE Customer.ID IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT Customer.ID FROM Customer INNER JOIN [Phone] ON [Customer].[Id] = [Phone].[CustomerId]
    ORDER BY [Customer].[Id]
    OFFSET (@PageNumber-1)*@RecordsPerPage rows
    FETCH NEXT @RecordsPerPage ROWS ONLY
)
```

This does leave a question, what is the point of this query when the calling application can just use their own OFFSET and FETCH NEXT? They already have the SQL to generate the initial dataset, all they need to do is add OFFSET / FETCH NEXT to the end of it and they have their own pagination without trying to wrap it in a procedure of some sort.

To create a comparison, would you create a stored procedure that accepts a SQL string and then filters specific fields by specific values? Or would the people calling that stored procedure just add a Where clause to their own queries instead?

Comment: I did not explain my desired result well enough.  The resulting dataset will be compiled into a list of complex objects, so the pagination I am after is not concerned with total number of records received, but with the number of primary (customer) records.

This function will be part of a DataAccessLibrary toolset that will implement a handful of parameters such as pagination, sort order, maximum records, and such so DataAccessLibraries that implement this toolset can be written very generically and applications that use them can specify needs without having to send the SQL directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use alias name for the cuplicated column.
For example:

```
WITH OriginalQuery AS (
    SELECT [Customer].[Id] as CustomerID,
           [Customer].[Name],
           [Customer].[Address],
           [Phone].[Id] as PhoneID,
           [Phone].[Type],
           [Phone].[Number]
    FROM [Customer] INNER JOIN [Phone] ON [Customer].[Id] = [Phone].[CustomerId]
)
```

now you can use the 2 ids whit the alias name for the next query.